# Как сделать одинаковую ширину для всех таблиц на странице?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть много таблиц одна за одной на одной странице. Как сделать так, чтобы у всех таблиц была одинаковая ширина? Задача сделать так, чтобы таблицы шли одна за одной и выглядели одинаково.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Device pd01-msw-001#                         </th><th>Interface  </th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-fas8200-001_2 e0M                 </td><td>Eth1/1     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-fas8200-001_1 e0M                 </td><td>Eth1/2     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-fas8200-002_2 e0M                 </td><td>Eth1/3     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-dor5000-015 c1/mgmt1              </td><td>Eth1/4     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-HW- pd01-onn-002 c3p2                       </td><td>Eth1/5     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-stg-003 m10                       </td><td>Eth1/6     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-stg-003 m20                       </td><td>Eth1/7     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-stg-004 m10                       </td><td>Eth1/8     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-HW- pd01-bks-016 ipmi                       </td><td>Eth1/9     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-bcp-001 mgm0                      </td><td>Eth1/11    </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-bcp-001 mgm1                      </td><td>Eth1/12    </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Device pd01-msw-002#           </th><th>Interface  </th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-fas9000-001_1 e0M   </td><td>Eth1/1     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-fas9000-001_2 e0M   </td><td>Eth1/2     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-fas8200-002_1 e0M   </td><td>Eth1/3     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-STG- pd01-dor5000-015 c2/mgmt1</td><td>Eth1/4     </td></tr>
<tr><td>-B- pd01-ilf-002 mgmt0         </td><td>Eth1/37    </td></tr>
<tr><td>-B- pd01-mlf-001 Eth1/2        </td><td>Eth1/49    </td></tr>
<tr><td>-B- pd01-mlf-002 Eth1/2        </td><td>Eth1/50    </td></tr>
<tr><td>-HW- pd01-bks-016 c0p2         </td><td>Eth1/51    </td></tr>
<tr><td>-B- pd01-mlf-001-002           </td><td>Po100      </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table> 

<table> 
...
</table>
```

Comment: надо полагать, вы про ширину столбцов, а не ширину самой таблицы? задайте в процентах

Comment: Да, скорее про ширину столбцов. Я хочу, чтобы все таблицы, а их у меня 10 штук, были одинаковые. Сейчас они у меня "прыгают", если можно так выразится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь в th ширину в процентах

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:70%">Device pd01-msw-002#</th>
    <th style="width:30%">Interface</th> 
  </tr>
```

далее как обычно